# SwiftUI @Published var inconsistently updating views

Tags: swiftui

I am working on a simple Reversi app built using SwiftUI. Recently I was updating my app and noticed a bug with the UI not updating to match the game state.

Here is a screenshot of an in-progress game:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the board after I press the undo button:

[image]

In the second screenshot, the middle-rightmost white piece should be black. I verified that the game state was correct by printing the `board` in a `didSet` block. For the first screenshot, this was the output (the array of pieces shown below corresponds to the pieces on the board, going left to right, then bottom to top):

```
[..., Optional(Dueling_Disks.Piece(isLight: false, id: 434BCE7B-D1B6-45E8-81AB-15F76007F76A)), Optional(Dueling_Disks.Piece(isLight: true, id: 63070399-84AB-43EE-9D03-BA21D64E0399)), ...,
Optional(Dueling_Disks.Piece(isLight: false, id: 9BBD7C56-5DE4-4249-8EC3-870AD8F9FBB1)), Optional(Dueling_Disks.Piece(isLight: false, id: D870C5F2-AF0F-4667-8CF1-0F7D81A82D17)), Optional(Dueling_Disks.Piece(isLight: true, id: 2C92104A-12F9-487F-A0BF-60ECEF8BF4B7)), ..., 
Optional(Dueling_Disks.Piece(isLight: true, id: 4F120B09-C0BE-4993-8324-43013D95083B)), Optional(Dueling_Disks.Piece(isLight: true, id: DD3316A7-FAF9-4AB3-853A-F1750856E430)), Optional(Dueling_Disks.Piece(isLight: true, id: 8796F231-BDEA-4930-AA1C-D3084E6D6C98)), ...]
```

This means that this output would be: `[black, white, (next row up) black, black, white, (next row up) white, white, white]`, which is correct and matches the screenshot. After pressing undo, here was the output:

```
[..., Optional(Dueling_Disks.Piece(isLight: false, id: 434BCE7B-D1B6-45E8-81AB-15F76007F76A)), Optional(Dueling_Disks.Piece(isLight: true, id: 63070399-84AB-43EE-9D03-BA21D64E0399)), ...,
Optional(Dueling_Disks.Piece(isLight: false, id: 9BBD7C56-5DE4-4249-8EC3-870AD8F9FBB1)), Optional(Dueling_Disks.Piece(isLight: false, id: D870C5F2-AF0F-4667-8CF1-0F7D81A82D17)), Optional(Dueling_Disks.Piece(isLight: false, id: 28FB5783-F0C2-426C-A03F-C5FCF3D342BA)), ...,
Optional(Dueling_Disks.Piece(isLight: true, id: 4F120B09-C0BE-4993-8324-43013D95083B)), Optional(Dueling_Disks.Piece(isLight: false, id: 22190EEE-D0C3-4E3F-AE18-F6577917CFD6)), ...]
```

This mean the output would be: `[black, white, (next row up) black, black, black, (next row up) white, black]`.

Clearly, the SwiftUI views do not fully match the change (with the middle-rightmost staying white instead of being black as the state dictates).

For background, I have an ObservableObject that stores the game state and publishes changes to the views:

```swift
class Game: ObservableObject {
    @Published var board = Board()
    @Published var times = GameState.times
    var pieces: [Piece] {
        board.pieces.filter({ $0 != nil}) as! [Piece]
    }
}
```

Both `board` and `times` are Structs (and are thus value-types).

I then initialize it in my GamesView:

```swift
struct GamesView: View {
    @StateObject private var game = Game()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GameView()
        }
        .environmentObject(game)
    }
}
```

My GamView just contains a BoardView (and some other UI views I omitted in this post):

```swift
struct GameView: View {
    var body: some View {
        BoardView()
    }
}
```

And the BoardView just contains a grid of 64 SquareViews:

```swift
// SizeRange is 1...8
struct BoardView: View {    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(SizeRange.reversed(), id: \.self) { row in
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(SizeRange, id: \.self) { column in
                        SquareView(column: column, row: row)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the SquareView will display the correctly colored piece (or none if there is no piece on the board):

```swift
struct SquareView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var game: Game
    @State var column: Int
    @State var row: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        let square = Square(column: column, row: row)
        let animation: Animation = .linear(duration: 0.3)
        ZStack {
            Button {
            } label: {
                Text("")
            }
            .disabled(game.board.gameOver)
            
            if let piece = game.board.pieces[square] {
                PieceView(isLight: piece.isLight)
                    .frame(width: boardLength / 16, height: boardLength / 16)
                    .transition(.opacity.animation(animation))
                    .animation(animation, value: game.board)
                    .zIndex(1)
            }
        }
//      .onChange(of: game.board.pieces) { _ in
//          print("PIECE", row, column)
//      }
    }
}
```

I also used the above commented out `.onChange` function to see if views were getting the update. What was really odd is when I placed a piece, all squares would give output but when I pressed undo, only some of the squares would give output (and it appears to be random for each launch of the app).

I was able to fix the issue by changing the code in my Game object to this:

```swift
@Published var board = Board() {
    willSet {
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}
```

Which from my understanding should do the same thing as just having an `@Published` variable.

Any help is very appreciated, this is really stumping me since I can't think of what might be causing the views to not reflect the data. Thanks so much for any help, and I am happy to give any other info if needed!

Comment: In order for `@Published` to work without `didSet` like this, `Board` needs to be a value type (ie a `struct`).

Comment: Board is a struct.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice is you have `@StateObject` in a `View` that does not do anything with any properties of the game in the `body` func when it changes so there is no reason to have it in that `View` because the body is being called pointlessly every time game is updated. Easy fix is to make it a let above the struct or if globals aren't your thing you could put in a singleton struct.

Second thing I notice is misuse of `ForEach`. You shouldn't compute `reversed` because that will slow down `body` and you shouldn't use `id:\.self` because that will break SwiftUI's structural identity (See Demystify SwiftUI WWDC 2021). You can however use ForEach on constant data and the syntax for that is `ForEach(0..<10)`. Note you can not dynamically add a row to the board game this way or it'll crash.

Third, the use of `@State` in SquareView is incorrect. `@State` is declaring a state of truth so it must have a default value. I think those properties should simply be lets. When a View is init with different lets from last time, body is called, which is part of SwiftUI’s magic.

I think it would be a better architecture to the board places 2D array in your data model and doing a `ForEach` over it. Rather than doing a `ForEach` over indices and then looking up the data.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback. Wouldn't including `@StateObject` at the top level there be the proper way to make it available to all subviews (using `.environmentObject`? For the `ForEach`, `SizeRange` is a constant that is used throughout my app (so I don't have identity concerns). Good point about the `@State` in SquareView

Comment: No the only requirement for environmentObject is that it conforms to ObservableObject. StateObject both ties the object’s lifecycle to the View and calls body on updates and you don’t need either of those features.

Comment: Ah got it, thanks for clarifying that! I’ll make those edits and see if anything changes.

Comment: I replaced the `@StateObject` with an `@EnvironmentObejct` (since I do actually need access to the board in the GamesView, just omitted that code from the post since I wanted to only show the relevant code). I am still seeing the issue though. Any ideas on what might be causing that? From my understanding all the views should get updated properly since they subscribe to changes via the `@EnvironmentObject` wrapper.

Comment: Most likely the problem is with your `ForEach` `id:\.self` try fixing that

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix the issue (I am also seeing this buggy behavior in other views as well that are not in a ForEach or anything). Thanks though.